# Breaking rails MVC: Sending data from model directly to view via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, multithreading

I am creating a [MUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD) using Rails. Here is what I got so far:
[image]

Right now I am working on a combat system. My combat system will work like this:

1. current_user sees characters and  non_player_characters in room
2. When current_user attacks another character, the other characters have 5 seconds to "deflect" the attack or they are hit. (Not fully implemented)
3. When current_user attacks an NPC, there is a 50% the NPC will deflect the attack
4. NPC will send attacks back to user and user will have to deflect attacks within the proper time interval (Not fully implemented).

In order to implement this combat system I decided I needed to use multithreading and timers:

```
  def initiate_attack
    Thread.new do
      sleep(5)
      hit_target
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
    end
  end

  def non_player_character_failed_to_deflect
    (1 + rand(10)) < 5
  end

  def is_non_player_character?
    @attack.target_type == "NonPlayerCharacter"
  end

  def hit_target
    if is_non_player_character?
      if non_player_character_failed_to_deflect
        damage_target
      else
        puts "Deflected"
      end
    else
      "hit player"
    end
  end

  def damage_target
    @target.update(power_level: @target.power_level - 10)
  end
```

This works as far as pure functionality is concerned, but the problem is I can't figure out how to get the strings back to the view so the user can see them. The user should see a message upon anyone initiating an attack, and upon the completion of an attack. I think the main issue with doing this is that by using multithreading MVC is broken because my threads in model are still running after the control has been returned to the controller and view.

So to summarize my question:
  1)How do I make it so my view is continuously updated using AJAX with data coming from the model?

For more information please visit the github page for this project:
[image]

Comment: I think you should try using web sockets instead of the approach you are currently using. A quick Google finds [this gem](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails). I have no experience with it personally, so I don't know how well it performs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to push data to the browser. To do that you have a few options:

- Use polling or long-polling. [message_bus](https://github.com/SamSaffron/message_bus) makes it very simple.
- Use websockets as suggested by Justin.
- Use another new technology to push events from the server like (server-sent events)[http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp].

I would give the message_bus gem a try.

EDIT: You might as well try (Sidekiq)[http://sidekiq.org/] to run the asynchronous code - I believe you'll find your code using it easier to maintain in the long run, specially compared to the approach of using threads directly.